# Focus issue with client side validations

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to test an input form. There are some client side validations which I want to check. I don't know about the internals, and I don't want to know. So it's a black box for me.

Steps I want to achieve:

1. click/focus on a text field, but input/type nothing
2. ckick/focus on another text field
3. now there should be a hint to the user, that the field from step #1 must not be empty

Here's the selenium script I have so far:

```
<tr><td>focus</td>         <td>id=name</td>                       <td></td> </tr>
<tr><td>type</td>          <td>id=name</td>                       <td></td> </tr>
<tr><td>focus</td>         <td>id=email</td>                      <td></td> </tr>
<tr><td>verifyVisible</td> <td>css=div.field-error.errorname</td> <td></td> </tr>
```

This works using Selenium IDE, but **only if the browser window itself has the focus**. If the Selenium IDE window is in focus, the test fails.

I have also modelled this using the webdriver. This always fails.

```
session.focus("id=name");
session.type("id=name","");
session.focus("id=email");
verifyTrue(session.isVisible("css=div.field-error.errorname"));
```

When the test fails, it's always because the `css=div.field-error.errorname` was not inserted into the DOM. So the verification script was not triggered somehow.

How do I manage to test this? How do I ensure the browser window to have the focus so the script will behave as it behaves in real world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
session.click("id=name");
session.sendKeys("id=name","");
session.click("id=email");
//wait for 3 seconds; if this works, you can use dynamic wait here
Thread.sleep(3000);
verifyTrue(session.isVisible("css=div.field-error.errorname"));
```

And you are using Selenium RC API, not Webdriver API, better to use Webdriver API.